# MQTT Java or C# server

Tags: c#, java, android, mqtt

Is there any known Java or C# server implementation of MQTT that is possible to use in commercial point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a server implementation in either of those languages at this time, but IBM provides WebSphere MQ which supports MQTT clients (and ships both Java and C clients) - since you mention a C# server I assume you are looking for a Windows-based server and WMQ can certainly run on Windows. Is there a specific reason why you are looking for server implementations in those languages?

Answer (score -1):

See [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: MSMQ is NOT an implementation of MQTT.